# Not able to install editor add-on for whole domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I have published a Sheets Editor Add-on on Chrome Web Store and my colleagues on the same G Suite domain can install it just fine, via the Web Store link.

However, the G Suite account admin doesn't have the option to install it for the whole domain. Anyone have a clue on where to start investigating this?

Edit: I have read in other places that it sometimes takes 3-4 days from publishing in Chrome Web Store until it shows up in the Marketplace. However this doesnt seem to be the case for us since we now have waited for about a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app has to be published on the G Suite Marketplace in order to enable a domain-wide installation.

If it is only published on the Chrome Web Store it has to be installed manually by each user.

**Choosing where to publish:** [GSuite Marketplace or Chrome WebStore](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-overview)

If it is published on the G Suite Marketplace it can be installed for the whole domain by admin account following this steps:

1. Sign in to [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com).
2. On the dashboard, click on the Apps icon:
3. Once there, go to 'Marketplace apps'
4. Add services to your domain
5. Search your App and choose to install it for the whole domain

And you are done, the app is installed for the whole domain.

[Install Marketplace apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks but it is precisely this procedure that doesn't work because there is not option to install for the whole domain. In fact, the app isn't even in the G Suite Marketplace, only in Chrome Web Store.

Comment: I've edited the answer with more information related to this topic.

Comment: Cool! I found that your link on publishing in the Marketplace, together with the App URL that I described in my own answer helped me get the app published.

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a way to publish the app even if it's not discoverable in the Marketplace.

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Go to G Suite Marketplace SDK
3. Under Publish in the left pane, Publish the add-on and get the App URL.
4. From the app URL, the domain admin can install the add-on for the whole domain.

[image]